# In SQL Server 2008, in DMV sys.dm_db_index_phsicial_stats, what does compressed_page_count mean in comparision with page_count

Tags: sql-server-2008, dmv

In SQL Server 2008, DMV `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats`, what does `compressed_page_count` mean in comparison with `page_count`. I have a table with the following info:

```
Object_id     Index_type_desc      avg_frag_in_percent    page_count     compressed_page_count        avg_page_space_used_in_percent       avg_record_size_in_bytes
5464654        CLUSTERED INDEX         0                    140992          1410                                        99.24                        111.2
4465464        NONCLUSTERED INDEX      0                    52532           526                                         99.69                         32.2
```

Does it mean, that the table has 140992 pages, but after compression it is brought down to 1410 pages or something else?

> `[BOL says:]` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx)
>   compressed_page_count: The number of compressed pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clustered index has 140992 pages, from which only 1410 are page compressed. Page compression is attempted only when it fills up, see [When Page Compression Occurs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280464.aspx):

> When a new table is created that has page compression, no compression
>   occurs. However, the metadata for the table indicates that page
>   compression should be used. As data is added to the first data page,
>   data is row-compressed. Because the page is not full, no benefit is
>   gained from page compression. When the page is full, the next row to
>   be added initiates the page compression operation. The whole page is
>   reviewed; each column is evaluated for prefix compression, and then
>   all columns are evaluated for dictionary compression. If page
>   compression has created enough room on the page for an additional row,
>   the row is added, and the data is both row- and page-compressed. If
>   the space gained by page compression minus the space that is required
>   for the CI structure is not significant, page compression is not used
>   for that page. Future rows either fit onto the new page or, if they do
>   not fit, a new page is added to the table. Similar to the first page,
>   the new page is not at first page-compressed.

It seems that in your case very few pages got compressed. Note that you still benefit from row compression.

Comment: Thank you. You have answered several of my questions in the past and including this one too. Thank you, appreciate it greatly. I wish you were in my `Phone_a_Friend_DBA` phone list.

Comment: Follow up question: So does the setting FILLFACTOR to 100 only work if the data in that section of the B-Tree has enough data fill up the page, right? So looks like in my table there are many non-FULL pages. Is there a way to force it to fill the pages entirely. Because for this table there are no updates. A million records are INSERTED (appended at the end) every day. So filling each page to FULL makes big difference. Your thoughts?

Comment: `FILLFACTOR` only plays a role during index build. You can try to rebuild the index and see if you get better compression. Afterwards, with an append only use pattern each page gets one and only one chance to compress. If it misses it, all subsequent inserts go in key order on the *next* page, so it will never trigger a compression on *this* page. What is your row size average [`avg_record_size_in_bytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx)?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The numbers I have in the post (above) are after REINDEXING with FILLFACTOR 100. Yes, I agree you that since the records are added in increasing order of the clustering key, there will never be a chance to add more rows to existing pages (and perform COMPRESSION). So how do I get around this? I REINDEXed the table several times today. `avg_record_size_in_bytes` is 111.257 & 38.268. So about 74 and 210 records go into each page. Interestingly `avg_page_space_used_in_percent` is 99.24% & 99.69 %. Now I am more confused !!

Comment: Also, I added `avg_record_size_in_bytes` & `avg_page_space_used_in_percent` to the original post above.

Comment: Perhaps compressing a page cannot yield 111 bytes (in average) so the compression is not done. It would indicate that data is not compressible beyond the row-compression format (ie. you do not have many repeated values in page, no repeated common prefix etc).

Comment: That is a good point. The data in the tables is a mixture of GUID's, date's and NULL values.Some of these GUIDs are repeated values, but some are random GUIDs. But majority of the date columns are all repeatable values. May be the cost of COMPRESSION (or the savings) is not big enough to actually compress the entire page. I wish there was a better answer, but it is what it is. Thank again.

Answer (score 0):

Below technet wiki article will help you in understanding what is meaning of column compressed_page_count

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25119.sql-server-what-does-column-compressed-page-count-value-signify-in-dmv-sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats.aspx